# I need guidance in building my first C# project

Tags: c#, windows, windows-xp

Hi I'm a PHP developer and I have some experience with Java. I'm trying to learn C# and my first project would be a program that starts the timer on a PC by clicking a button on another PC in the network. The problem is, I don't know where to start? What do I need to read up on? The OS for both PCs is Windows XP so they're desktop apps. I'd appreciate any help from you C# gurus. I hope my start as a C# programmer would be successful. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the communication channel you should use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) - [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFCS.aspx) is an article showing how a simple client/server is written.

In terms of a UI for these - you may want to use [winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb.aspx) or [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation). WPF is the future, but winforms are easier to get to grips with. There is a Microsoft website dedicated to [both](http://windowsclient.net/) of them.

There are several timer classes in the framework - see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) article for comparisons.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .NET 3+, then [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) is generally the recommended technology.  It is basically a merge of .NET remoting, web services, etc. into one library.

**Edit:**  Sorry, my answer was based on Midhat's answer.  Oded gave the best guidance since he actually read the question!  WCF is only what you would use to communicate from one application to another.  In your scenario, you can set up WCF as a TCP/IP server/client.

Answer (score 1):

You need .Net remoting http://www.beansoftware.com/net-tutorials/net-remoting-tutorial.aspx